# codeigniter model function with and / or query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this function in model

```
 function select($table,$match,$or){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->where($match)->or_where($or);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $query_result = $query->result();
        return $query_result;
    }
```

and in controller

```
$post = array("class"=>"XI","section"=>"A","stream"=>"Medical");
$data = $this->main_model->select("class_subjects",array("class"=>$post['class'],"section"=>"all","stream"=>$post['stream']),$post);
            print_r($data);
```

I am not getting any error but this is printing whole data of table. how can i match `class='XI' and stream='Medical' and (section='A' or section='all')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function select($table,$match,$or)
{
    $query = $this->db
        ->select("*")
        ->from($table)
        ->group_start()
            ->where($match)
        ->group_end()
        ->group_start()
            ->or_where($or)
        ->group_end()
        ->get();

    $strSql = $this->db->last_query();

    return $query->result();
}
```

if that won't work - print out the $strSql Variable and post the Query here.